# How are uniform hashing functions applied?

Tags: hash

According to CLRS page 267, a class of uniform hashing functions are defined, but I am wondering how these functions are applied when hashing a group of keys.

Do we choose a function randomly every time we want to calc a hash value, or we choose a function randomly and use it to calc every hash value for keys in this group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to randomly choose a hashing function every time you wanted to hash a key, then you'd end up with a mess because different hashing functions create different hash values for the same key. That is, if your key was "foobar", then hash function A would compute a different value for it than hash function B. That wouldn't be useful.

So you choose a hashing function and apply that to every key in that group. Typically, you'll use the same hash function for all keys in your system. In general, there's no particular advantage to having multiple hashing functions in your program. (Yes, I know there are special cases.)